# Changing Centre of 3D Viewport

Tags: 3d-view

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question; I am very new to the program.

All the basic movement controls (Orbiting, zooming, strafing) seem to be based around the centre of the viewport. I am trying to work with something fairly far away from this point, and it is very difficult to control. All movement is very sensitive (do you know what I mean?). Is there any way to change this point? Or is there any other way to circumvent this problem? Sorry again if the answer is something obvious.

Comment: If you LMB click anywhere in the viewport, the 3D cursor will go there. Now press Alt-Home and your view should focus on the 3D cursor.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT2mtoDnSzM https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html

Answer (score 1):

Select an object by <kbd>LMB</kbd> over it and then press <kbd>numpad period</kbd> to focus on it.

But if you want to focus on an emtpy space and pivot around it, <kbd>LMB</kbd> to move the 3D cursor to that spot then  <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>home</kbd>